# Embedding powershell within vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, embed

I have a powershell script which I call using a .vbs file. This reduces the effort of the user to go to cmd every time,type powershell and then calling the .ps1 file.
The vbs script directly opens powershell in a new cmd window calling the ps1 file.

The VB script is:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit C:\Scripts\anydrive.ps1")
```

What I want to achieve now is, Can I embed the **.ps1** file inside **.vbs file** so that I have a single .vbs file which I can circulate to users rather than having 2 separate files.

Comment: By embedding I mean , can the entire code of .ps1 somehow be used in .vbs file itself or by any other logic which ultimately leaves me with one file only. Hope my query is clear.

Comment: You could probably save the contents as a string and send the string as an argument to the `-command` parameter. Question is though, why don't you just use one or the other...?

Comment: I was using only .ps1 file earlier but that made users in my office a bit annoying by everytime opening powershell explicitly. By giving them the .vbs file , they now only just need to double click on the .vbs file which calls the .ps1 file in the backend and provides them .ps1 menu.

Comment: I see. Whatever it is that you're doing in powershell you can almost certainly *also* do natively in vbscript so you may be overcomplicating matters here.

Comment: Oh is it. In the powershell what I'm doing is fetching the disk space results of any drive of a remote server through WMI object. Drive letter and server name will be entered by user. I'm not sure if wmiobject can be invoked using VBS. Any idea?

Comment: Google is your friend. Yes you can call [WMI from VBS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.heyscriptingguy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Matt. But I'll have to change the entire code in that case and convert it to vbs, thats painful. Can it be done what arco444 suggested above to save entire content of ps1 as a string and pass it as an arguement to -command.I understand this logic but not sure of the syntax.

Comment: Why do you need VBS and PowerShell? User could just double click on ps1 assuming your execution policy is set correctly

Comment: Thanks Matt. Our environment is highly restricted one, no convenient policies are set. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

You can do what you're asking. The easiest way to is to encode it as a base64 string, perhaps something like this (this is a one time thing):

```powershell
$script = Get-Content C:\Scripts\anydrive.ps1 -Raw
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($script)
$encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$encoded | clip  # copy it to the clipboard
```

Then you paste it into the VBScript encoded.

You would call powershell like this:

```powershell
powershell.exe -NoExit -EncodedCommand $e
```

(`$e` in this case refers to the encoded command string or the VBscript variable that contains it).

## But, why?

If you don't want users to have to open powershell and manually load the file, and you want something they can double click on, why not just make a shortcut for them? The shortcut would just target the exact same command line you're calling from the VBscript.

Comment: "But, why?" - common sense prevails :)

Comment: Thanks Braintist and everyone for the replies.